# Firing an animation when aligned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a splitscrolling website and it's working great. But i have one problem, when the user stops scrolling it fires a function called alignWhenIdle and what this does is align the columns so they become "one".

Now that is working nicely but i can't seem to target a specific part of the column that aligns. let's say when the number 2 column aligns ( see image ) i want to be able to fire an animation. I tried using a callback but that fires a function every time the columns are aligned.

[image]

This is my JS:

```
(function ($) {
var top = 0;
var contentHeight, contents, totalHeight;
var locked = false;
var timeout;

var align = function () {
    var pos = (top + $(window).scrollTop());
    var snapUp = 0 - (pos % contentHeight) < (contentHeight / 2);
    var multiplier = snapUp
        ? Math.ceil(pos / contentHeight)
        : Math.floor(pos / contentHeight);
    var newTop = contentHeight * multiplier;
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: newTop + totalHeight }, 200);
    locked = false;
};

var reset = function () {
    contentHeight = $('.right').height();
    contents = $('.right > .content').length;
    totalHeight = contentHeight * (contents - 1);
    top = (0 - totalHeight);
};

var scrollRight = function () {
    $('.right').css('top', (top + $(window).scrollTop()) + 'px');
};

var alignWhenIdle = function (delay) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(align, delay);
};

$(document).on('ready', function () {
    reset();
    scrollRight();
});

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    locked = true;
    scrollRight();
});

$(window).on('mouseup', function (e) {
    if (locked) {
        align();
    }
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    locked = true;
    reset();
    scrollRight();
    alignWhenIdle(300);
});

$(window).on('mousewheel', function (e) {
    alignWhenIdle(300);
});

$(window).on("keyup", function (e) {
     alignWhenIdle(300);
});

})(jQuery);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ev3B8/

Any help is much appreciated,

Cheers

Comment: sorry, can't get into your problem... You'd like to fire an animation (as I understand inside of block 2) after your scrolling is done? or at the moment of scrolling?

Comment: not getting your prob..

Comment: sorry english isn't my native language. But yes if u stop scrolling at block 2 and when it aligns there i want to be able to fire an animation

Comment: you wants to fire animation only on block 2 ?? means middle of the columns..?

Comment: Yes Indra, but in my actual code there are more than 3 blocks don't know if that changed anything. Thanks for looking into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/5T9Y8/

Scroll till the column 2 and see result...

In the method align I've added a callback:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: newTop + totalHeight }, 200, function(){
  $(".animate").animate({ marginLeft: "200px" },300);
});
```

Works well, did you need exactly that?

**EDIT**

You should just check for some condition.

E.g. based on this solution [Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling) you can build this:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: newTop + totalHeight }, 200, function(){
  if (isScrolledIntoView(".animate")) $(".animate").animate({ marginLeft: "200px" },300);
});
```

See updated solution here http://jsfiddle.net/5T9Y8/1/

This is only one way, I'm really sure there is a way to do it even better. E.g. you can calculate the current elements which are shown and then just find the things only inside of them.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what i need, but it fires every time the column is aligned so on 1, 2 and 3. And that's the problem :'(

Comment: check this out, seems to handle your request

Comment: No problem :) all for your smile :)

Answer (score 0):

> I tried using a callback but that fires a function every time the columns are aligned.

Use [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method for functioning only once instead of on.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. But that still doesn't solve the issue of firing an animation on a specific part of the column :(